# Separating a PDE into two ODE's. Made an attempt but unsure if I'm correct.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For the equation

$\frac{\partial^2}{{\partial}x^2}(IE\frac{{\partial^2}u}{{\partial}x^2}) = \mu(\frac{{\partial^2}u}{{\partial}t^2})$

with $E$ a function of x, derive two ODE's by separation of variables.

---

I greatly appreciate your help/advice. I'm pretty unsure with how to handle derivatives like this. This is my best attempt, I've been working on this one for quite a while.

http://mathbin.net/51398

Comment: Can you tell what $I$ is? Is $\mu$ a function? I guess not, but better ask.

Comment: I and mu are constants. E is a function of x

Comment: I would just fill in $u(x,t) = f(x)g(t)$ and compute it directly. It will give you a fourth derivative in $f$, then you can just separate them and solve the ODEs. I tried it and just got a fourth order ODE of $f$ and a second order of $g$.

Where are you stuck in this process?

Comment: Your Ansatz is perfectly correct.

Comment: I am struggling with this problem... So far this is what I have. Is this correct? I really appreciate the help provided so far. Thank you.

Putting $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$ as mentioned:

$\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}\left( I\mbox{E}\left( x \right)\frac{d^{2}X}{dx^{2}}T \right)\; =\; \mu \frac{d^{2}T}{dt^{2}}X$

Now:

$\frac{d^{4}X}{dx^{4}}\left( I\mbox{E}\left( x \right)T \right)\; =\; \mu \frac{d^{2}T}{dt^{2}}X$

Simplifying again:

$\frac{d^{4}X}{dx^{4}}\frac{\mbox{E}\left( x \right)}{\mu X}\; =\; \frac{d^{2}T}{dt^{2}}\frac{1}{TI}$

Is this correct so far? I know the final step put it = to a constant

Comment: You need to use the product (Leibniz) rule when you differentiate $E(x) X''(x)$. Like this: $(EX'')'' = E'' X'' + 2 E' X''' + E X''''$.

Comment: oh of course..... how silly of me :( thank you Hans Lundermark.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ ,

Then $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\biggl(IE(x)\dfrac{\partial^2(X(x)T(t))}{\partial x^2}\biggr)=\mu\dfrac{\partial^2(X(x)T(t))}{\partial t^2}$

$T(t)\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}\biggl(IE(x)\dfrac{d^2X(x)}{dx^2}\biggr)=\mu X(x)\dfrac{d^2T(t)}{dt^2}$

$\dfrac{1}{\mu X(x)}\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}\biggl(IE(x)\dfrac{d^2X(x)}{dx^2}\biggr)=\dfrac{1}{T(t)}\dfrac{d^2T(t)}{dt^2}=-(f(s))^2$

$\begin{cases}\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}\biggl(IE(x)\dfrac{d^2X(x)}{dx^2}\biggr)+\mu(f(s))^2X(x)=0\\\dfrac{d^2T(t)}{dt^2}+(f(s))^2T(t)=0\end{cases}$